# itfoxtec - Net Framework 4.5

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

IDP Initiate SSO I try to implement .Net Framework 4.5 my entire application running 4.5.I have downloaded source from ITfoxtec-Identity-Saml2 and I convert 4.5 Asp.net web forms. I'm trying to build application I got exception.

"**Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The primary reference "ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, Version=4.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2dd6b1fbf7645f92, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".    DemoSAML2IntegrationIDP**   "

it is possible to convert 4.5..please suggest.how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert the ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 library to .NET 4.5 because the functionality used by the library first becomes available from .NET 4.6.1.